# Im new to code, Why My userform not redirecting to same link or not auto form reset

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Created userform by using HTML

it is successfully returning data to google sheets but it is not reset the form after click submit.

Can anyone help me please, I'm new to this code

if possible can anyone tell me with the next button how to write a multi-level form, give me any sample code or file plz....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Factory Order Form</title>
    <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
      
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
    

   Entry Name:
   <input type="text" style="font-weight: bold;" name="Entry_Name"  size='10' required>


    <label for="Store_Name" required>Store Name   :</label> 
    <select id="Store_Name" name="Store_Name"  >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Gokul - Lord Sinha Road">Gokul - Lord sinha road</option>
    <option value="Gokul Bhog Anadya">Gokul Bhog - Anadya</option>
    </select>
    

      Delivery Date:
      <input type="date" name="Delivery_Date" size='4' required>
      
      Delivery time:
      <input type="time" name="Delivery_time" size='4'required></h3>
    
      <br>  
    
    <hr><hr> 


    <br><br>
    
    <label for="Product1">Product1   :</label>
    <select id="Product1" name="Product1">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
    </select>

   
     <label>Item_Name1 :
        <select id="Item_Name1" name="Item_Name1">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </select>


    Qty1   :
    <input type="Number" name="Qty1" > 

    <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
    <select id="KG_PC1" name="KG_PC1">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="KG">KG</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    </select>



    Rate1   :
    <input type="Number" name="Rate1"> 
    

    Size1   :
    <input type="text" name="Size1"> 
    
    Order No.1   :
    <input type="Number" name="Order_No1"> 
   
   <br>
    
    <div class="block">
    <button type="submit" class="action">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
    function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
     google.script.host.close();//close this dialogbox
    }
    );
 </body>
</html>
```

---------------------gs code---------

```js
    function doGet(e) {
      var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');
      return htmlOutput.evaluate();
    }
     
    
    
    function addNewItem(form_data)
    {
       var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var of = ss1.getSheetByName("Prod data Submit");
     
       
       of.getRange("b1").setValue(data.Entry_Name)
       of.getRange("b2").setValue(data.Store_Name)
       of.getRange("b3").setValue(data.Delivery_Date)
       of.getRange("b4").setValue(data.Delivery_time
    
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you are setting some values to your spreadsheet via `google.script.run.addNewItem(this);`, and you want to reset the form fields after this is done.

#### Solution:

In order to do that, you should use [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) to execute a callback function if `addNewItem` executes successfully, and reset the form fields. An easy way to reset those fields is using [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

Therefore, your `script` tag could be something like this:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resetForm)
                     .addNewItem(this);
  });
  function resetForm() {
    document.querySelector("#myform").reset();
  }
</script>
```

#### Other issues:

There are several other issues here. If you are using the exact code you provided, it's not possible that you are currently able to write data to the spreadsheet:

- In the HTML you provided, the `<script>` tag is not getting closed (`</script>`).
- In `addNewItem`, the parameter is called `form_data`, but then you are using `data`. Both variables should match, or you'll get an error.
- You are using [google.script.host.close()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close()), which is used to close a dialog or sidebar, but has no place in a web app like yours.

Comment: @lamblichus I have another query can you help me please, in above HTML from Product1  to Order No.1 is one div like this I have product 2 div, product 3 div ..... till product 20 div so I need button "show more "  after 5 div along with submit button if i click"show more" button next 5 will show  or if iclick submit data will submit, tq

Comment: @DurgaPrasad Consider posting a new question, since this is totally unrelated to your original one.

Comment: @lamblichus  here is link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736451/hide-set-of-code-or-in-between-div-in-html-form-when-i-click-show-button-it-will