# Hide set of code or in between div in html form when i click show button it will show or If click submit it will submit

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, userform

In below HTML from Product1 to Order No.1 is one set like this I have product 2 div, product 3 div till product 20 set so I need the button with name "show more " along with submit button if I click "show more" button next 5 will show or if I click submit data will submit, tq

I tried with document.getElementById("blabla").style.display = "visible"; by using onclick calling function.But when I'm clicking show, it is visible and submitted at once  (not added in below code)

Due to char limit below has limit code(till set 10)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXSCd.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <title>Factory Order Form</title>
        <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
          
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
        <base target="_top">
      
      </head>
      <style>
      .form-r{
      width: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 3px solid gray;
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom:15px;
     }
     
      </style>  
      
      <body>
    <h1>Internal Order Form</h1>
    <form id="myform" >
       <h3>
       <div class="form-r">
       Entry Name:
       <input type="text" name="Entry_Name"  id="Entry_Name"  required>
    
    
        <label for="Store_Name" >Store Name   :</label> 
        <select id="Store_Name" name="Store_Name" required >
        <option value="" ></option>  
        <option value="Gokul - Lord Sinha Road">Gokul - Lord sinha road</option>
        <option value="Gokul Bhog Anadya">Gokul Bhog - Anadya</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
       Delivery Date:
          <input type="date" name="Delivery_Date" id="Delivery_Date" required >
          
        Delivery time:
          <input type="time" name="Delivery_time" id="Delivery_time" required >
        
        </div> 
            
        </h3>
        <hr><hr> 
    
    
        <div >
        <label for="Product1">Product1   :</label>
        <select id="Product1" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product1" required >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
    
          <label>Item Name1 :
          <input list="Item_Name1" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name1" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name1" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
    
        
        
    
        Qty1   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC1">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC1" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC1">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate1   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate1" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size1   :
        <input type="text" name="Size1" id="Size1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.1   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No1" id="Order_No1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
       
        
       
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product2">Product2   :</label>
        <select id="Product2" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product2" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
        <label>Item Name2 :
          <input list="Item_Name2" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name2" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name2" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
        
    
    
        
        Qty2   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_P">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC2" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC2">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate2   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate2" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size2   :
        <input type="text" name="Size2" id="Size2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.2   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No2" id="Order_No2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
       
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product3">Product3   :</label>
        <select id="Product3" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product3" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
       
       <label>Item Name3 :
          <input list="Item_Name3" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name3" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name3" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
    
        Qty3   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC3" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC3">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate3   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate3" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size3   :
        <input type="text" name="Size3" id="Size3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.3   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No3" id="Order_No3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
      <div >
        <label for="Product4">Product4   :</label>
        <select id="Product4" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product4" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
    
       <label>Item Name4 :
          <input list="Item_Name4" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name4" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name4" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
    
        
    
        Qty4   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC4" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC4">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate4   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate4" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size4   :
        <input type="text" name="Size4" id="Size4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.4   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No4" id="Order_No4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product5">Product5   :</label>
        <select id="Product5" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product5" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
         
         <label>Item Name5 :
          <input list="Item_Name5" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name5" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name5" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
        
    
        Qty5   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty5" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC5" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC5">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate5   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate5" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size5   :
        <input type="text" name="Size5" id="Size5" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.5   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No5" id="Order_No5" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
      
    
      
       <hr> 
    
    
        <div >
        <label for="Product6">Product6   :</label>
        <select id="Product6" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product6" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
         
         <label>Item Name6 :
          <input list="Item_Name6" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name6" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name6" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
    
    
    
        Qty6   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty6" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC6" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC6">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate6   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate6" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size6   :
        <input type="text" name="Size6" id="Size6" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.6   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No6" id="Order_No6" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
       
        
       
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product7">Product7   :</label>
        <select id="Product7" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product7" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
          
          <label>Item Name7 :
          <input list="Item_Name7" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name7" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name7" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
         
        
    
        Qty7   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty7" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC7" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC7">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate7   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate7" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size7   :
        <input type="text" name="Size7" id="Size7" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.7   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No7" id="Order_No7" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
       
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product8">Product8   :</label>
        <select id="Product8" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product8" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
         <label>Item Name8 :
          <input list="Item_Name8" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name8" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name8" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
        
    
        Qty8   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty8" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC8" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC8">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate8   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate8" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size8   :
        <input type="text" name="Size8" id="Size8" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.8   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No8" id="Order_No8" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
      <div >
        <label for="Product9">Product9   :</label>
        <select id="Product9" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product9" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
         <label>Item Name9 :
          <input list="Item_Name9" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name9" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name9" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
        
    
        Qty9   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty9" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC9" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC9">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate9   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate9" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size9   :
        <input type="text" name="Size9" id="Size9" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.9   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No9" id="Order_No9" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div> 
    
    
    
       <div >
        <label for="Product10">Product10   :</label>
        <select id="Product10" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product10" >
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
        <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
        </select>
       
         <label>Item Name10 :
          <input list="Item_Name10" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name10" /></label>
          <datalist id="Item_Name10" >
          <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
            <?!= getVendors(); ?>
          </datalist>
        
    
        Qty10   :
        <input type="Number" name="Qty10" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
        <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
        <select id="KG_PC10" style="width: 100px;"  name="KG_PC10">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
        <option value="KG">KG</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        </select>
    
        Rate10   :
        <input type="Number" name="Rate10" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
       
        Size10   :
        <input type="text" name="Size10" id="Size10" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       
          
        Order No.10   :
        <input type="Number" name="Order_No10" id="Order_No10" style="width: 100px;"  > 
       </div>
    
      
    
       <h2> 
        <button id="butn" >Submit</button>
       </h2>
       
    
        </form>
        <script>
      document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resetForm)
                         .addNewItem(this);
      });
      
      function resetForm() {
        document.querySelector("#myform").reset();
      alert("Order Submited")
      }
     
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
    
    
    ---------------JS Code-----------
    
    
    function doGet(e) {
      var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');
      return htmlOutput.evaluate();
    }
     
    
    
    function addNewItem(data)
    {
       var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var of = ss1.getSheetByName("Prod data Submit");
     
       
       of.getRange("b1").setValue(data.Entry_Name)
       of.getRange("b2").setValue(data.Store_Name)
       of.getRange("b3").setValue(data.Delivery_Date)
       of.getRange("b4").setValue(data.Delivery_time)
    
    of.appendRow([data.Product1,data.Item_Name1 ,data.Qty1,data.KG_PC1,data.Rate1,data.Size1,data.Order_No1 ]);
    of.appendRow([data.Product2,data.Item_Name2 ,data.Qty2,data.KG_PC2,data.Rate2,data.Size2,data.Order_No2 ]);
    of.appendRow([data.Product3,data.Item_Name3 ,data.Qty3,data.KG_PC3,data.Rate3,data.Size3,data.Order_No3 ]);
    of.appendRow([data.Product4,data.Item_Name4 ,data.Qty4,data.KG_PC4,data.Rate4,data.Size4,data.Order_No4 ]);
    of.appendRow([data.Product5,data.Item_Name5 ,data.Qty5,data.KG_PC5,data.Rate5,data.Size5,data.Order_No5 ]);
    
    //-------more code here
        
    prod_dt_submit()
    return data
     
    }
    
    
    
    
    function prod_dt_submit() {
    
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var pds = ss.getSheetByName("Prod data Submit");
      var mpd = ss.getSheetByName("Master data Prod");
      
      var pdslr = pds.getLastRow()
      var mpdlr = mpd.getLastRow()+1
    
      var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
     var dn = pds.getRange("b1").getDisplayValue();
     var mae= pds.getRange("b2").getDisplayValue();
     var pd = pds.getRange("b3").getDisplayValue();
     var pt = pds.getRange("b4").getDisplayValue();
     var fsno = pds.getRange("b5").getDisplayValue();
     
    
    
    
     for(var k = mpdlr ; k <((mpdlr+pdslr)-6) ; k++){
     mpd.getRange(k,1).setValue(ts);
     mpd.getRange(k,3).setValue(dn);
     mpd.getRange(k,4).setValue(mae);
     mpd.getRange(k,5).setValue(pd);
     mpd.getRange(k,6).setValue(pt);
     mpd.getRange(k,2).setValue(fsno);
    
     }
    
    
     mpd.getRange(mpdlr,7,(pdslr-6),7).setValues(pds.getRange(7,1,(pdslr-6),7).getDisplayValues());
    
    
      pds.getRange("B1:B4").clearContent();
      
      pds.getRange("A7:G").clearContent(); 
      
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    function getVendors() {
      var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Item_Names");
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
      var data    = myRange.getValues();
      var optionsHTML = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
        optionsHTML += '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
      };
      return optionsHTML;
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is all messed up. You have multiple body tags. Please review your code, beautify it, read through [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your post. Thanks

Comment: @Aerials , thanks for your reply can you please give me a sample code (forgot my code) with dummy data . all i need is, assume if we have two text boxes in html code , when i  open form  it will show only one text box with "show more" and "submit" button, if i click show more next text will apear with the same two boxes