# Google Sheet custom HTML prompt doesn't run my gs script

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

Tried to run a script from an html message box. But the script doesn't run at all. The code is below:

**CreateNewEmployeeSheet.gs**

```
function show_form() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("form.html")
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(200);
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Neue Mitarbeiter hinzufügen');
}


function resulT(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange("H3").setValue("OK");
}
```

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="fristarbeiter" name="drone" value="fristarbeiter"
            checked>
      <label for="huey">Fristarbeiter</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="feststelle" name="drone" value="feststelle">
      <label for="dewey">Feststelle</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function form_data(){

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
    // do something with the response here to indicate success
}).withFailureHandler(error => {
    console.error("appendData() ERROR: " + error.message);
    alert("appendData() ERROR: " + error.message);
}).resulT();        

        var values = [{
          "fristarbeiter":$("input[name=fristarbeiter]:checked").val(),
        }];
        closeIt()
      };

function closeIt(){
        google.script.host.close()
      };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "debug" output is:

**Ho {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…/js/4186432569-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:195:263)"}**

Is there a problem with access allowance?

Comment: Runnig your code from the editor works for me without issues. Can you show / explain how you call it from the html message box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part of your code and retry again, should be working now

From:

```
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("form.html")
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(200);
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Neue Mitarbeiter hinzufügen');
```

To:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form')
var ui=html.evaluate().setWidth(300) .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Neue Mitarbeiter hinzufügen');
```

Comment: i've changed the code and actually, I'm getting a "permission denied" error message. Thanks for the answer tho. I have to repost question

Comment: I see, how come you are getting denied from your own worksheet lol. Maybe you should try `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`

Comment: it does work if I run it inside gs script but html kind of doesn't have permission to run functions

Comment: Html is allow `code.gs` to be executed within `script`, although I not sure how to write `withFailurehandler`, maybe you can refer to this recent thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697737/im-new-to-code-why-my-userform-not-redirecting-to-same-link-or-not-auto-form-re